# Why isn't my partition appearing?

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-explorer, disk-management, drive-letter

I have a partition on my system drive that appears in *Computer Management* → *Storage* → *Disk Management*, but not under *This PC* → *Devices and Drives* in File Explorer.

Why isn't my partition appearing in File Explorer?

[image: joined screenshots: “Computer Management” and “File Explorer”]

Ramhound said (in [a comment that has been deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/1401495/why-isnt-my-partition-appearing#comment2113666_1401495)):

> You need to assign it an actual drive letter

But haven't I fulfilled this? I named the missing partition A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a drive letter assigned. Drive letters in Explorer and Disk management tool are put in parentheses as you can see from your own screenshot

[image: Diskmgmt drive letter and paths]

The string on each volume is its [label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_(computing)#Volume_label). You need to select *Change Drive Letter and Paths* in the context menu and **add a new drive letter**. There you can also mount the drive under any NTFS folders, but that's probably not what most people want